# JS: Why does deleting undefined return false and deleteing other basic data types return true

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I was just playing around in the Node.js command line and remembered that `undefined` is not a reserved keyword in JS and it's totally valid to declare a variable named `undefined` like

```js
let undefined = 7;
```

I declared this variable but after seeing that Node.js does not override the default `undefined` value (aka the variable exists but can't be accessed as it uses the `undefined` by default), I tried to delete it, using the `delete` statement. My output looked like this:

```
> delete undefined
false
```

This made me curious, as I've never seen delete return false in the Node.js CL (it even returns true if you try to delete non-declared variables or similiar like `delete asdasddsa`).

Now I tried what would happen if I used it like

```
> delete null
true
```

This also works for all other primitive values as `true`, `1` or `"string"`.

So why does this return false but returns true for null? I'm just curious and trying to gain a deeper understanding of how the language works

Comment: [12.5.3 `delete` Operator](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-delete-operator) -> [12.5.3.2 Runtime Semantics: Evaluation](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-delete-operator-runtime-semantics-evaluation) -> Steps 3, 4b, 5e

Comment: If you take a look at the result of `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(self, 'undefined')` you will see that `configurable` is `false` which means that the property cannot be changed or deleted.

Comment: Those code lines don't actually do anything, `delete` deletes object properties, not objects or primitives. The Runtime Semantics Andreas has linked, explains the returned values.

Comment: Ah, I understand, thanks for the explanation. I know that you can make properties non-configureable using `Object.freeze` or `Object.defineProperty`, but are there any more natural occurences of this one? I haven't encountered any so far

Comment: You can use this `Object.keys(self).filter(k => !Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(self, k).configurable)` to get an array of all properties that are not configurable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior is defined in [12.5.3.2 Runtime Semantics: Evaluation](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-delete-operator-runtime-semantics-evaluation) of the [`delete` operator](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-delete-operator), and more precisely in steps 3, 4b and 5e

> 1. Let `ref` be the result of evaluating `UnaryExpression`.
> 2. `ReturnIfAbrupt(ref)`.
> 3. If `Type(ref)` is not Reference, return `true`.
> 4. If `IsUnresolvableReference(ref)` is `true`, then
>    a. Assert: `IsStrictReference(ref)` is `false`.
>    b. Return `true`.
> 5. If `IsPropertyReference(ref)` is `true`, then
>    a. If `IsSuperReference(ref)` is `true`, throw a `ReferenceError` exception.
>    b. Let `baseObj` be ! `ToObject(GetBase(ref))`.
>    c. Let `deleteStatus` be ? `baseObj.[[Delete]](GetReferencedName(ref))`.
>    d. If `deleteStatus` is `false` and `IsStrictReference(ref)` is `true`, throw a `TypeError` exception.
>    e. Return `deleteStatus`.
> 6. Else,
>    a. Assert: `ref` is a Reference to an Environment Record binding.
>    b. Let `bindings` be `GetBase(ref)`.
>    c. Return ? `bindings.DeleteBinding(GetReferencedName(ref))`.

> **Note**
> When a `delete` operator occurs within strict mode code, a `SyntaxError` exception is thrown if its `UnaryExpression` is a direct reference to a variable, function argument, or function name. In addition, if a `delete` operator occurs within strict mode code and the property to be deleted has the attribute `{ [[Configurable]]: false }`, a `TypeError` exception is thrown.